# Tensorflow Dataset Batch Timestamps Across Tuples

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I currently have a 3D `np.array` called `heatmap_3d` in the form of `(timestamp,rows,cols,channels)` and a 2D `np.array` called `other_features` in the form of `(timestamp,other_features)`. I want to convert them to a tensorflow `Dataset`, window them and combine them. Since they are of different dimensions, however, I've had to combine them in a tuple across time and load them with a generator as below:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: iter(zip(heatmap_3d, other_features)), 
    output_types=(tf.float64, tf.float64),
    output_shapes=((8,9,1),(59))
)

ds = ds.window(7, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
```

which when printed looks something like this:

```
(<_VariantDataset shapes: (8, 9, 1), types: tf.float64>, <_VariantDataset shapes: (59,), types: tf.float64>)
...
(<_VariantDataset shapes: (8, 9, 1), types: tf.float64>, <_VariantDataset shapes: (59,), types: tf.float64>)
```

Beforehand when I was only dealing with `other_features`, after I windowed the dataset I simply had to call

```
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(7))
```

but now that it is in tuples lambda is receiving the tuple as two arguments, and hence can't be batched this way. Simply turning the mapping function to `lambda x,y: (x.batch(7),y.batch(7))` doesn't work either as the return value must be a dataset. How do I go about batching the timestamps together akin to when I was only dealing with `other_features`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output a Dataset in flat_map (as you said) while keeping them in a tuple-like format. When you have to create basically tuples from examples in two Datasets, then the `zip()` method for the Dataset class comes in handy. You could try the following:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: iter(zip(heatmap_3d, other_features)), 
    output_types=(tf.float64, tf.float64),
    output_shapes=((8,9,1),(59))
)

ds = ds.window(7, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)

ds = ds.flat_map(lambda x, y: tf.data.Dataset.zip((x.batch(7), y.batch(7))))
```